# Swift ios 8 issue not update app badge icon but its working in ios 9 Error - Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission

Tags: swift, ios8, push-notification

I have create one app on xcode 7 using swift language , and i have app register for push notification . The Problem is in ios 8 , app i ask for allow pushnotification message in both (ios8 and ios9) but app run on ios 8 its return this message **Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application** when i have open the app that time i get pushnotification in This Function **IOS8** and **IOS9**

```
func application( application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        // print("Notification received2: \(userInfo)")
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber  =  0;}
```

but when i close the app then i cant able to see any notification in **IOS8** But is working in **IOS9** 
Here is my code

```
 let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge,.Sound], categories: nil)


        application.registerUserNotificationSettings( settings )
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

What is missing for **IOS8** please give me solution

By Nishant Chandwani 
 Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

```
if CFloat(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion())! >= 8.0 {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings.settingsForTypes(([.Sound, .Alert, .Badge]), categories: nil))
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
else {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert]))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this. 

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

Comment: The question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c".